# trying to didvide the List Equally among 3 threads and write to excel

Tags: java

i Have a List of Courses as shown below

```
List<Course> documents = Arrays.asList(
            new Course(1, "Spring MVC Xls View", new Date()),
            new Course(2, "Spring MVC Xlsx View", new Date()),
            new Course(3, "Spring MVC XlsxStreaming View", new Date()),
            new Course(4, "Spring MVC Xls View", new Date()),
            new Course(5, "Spring MVC Xlsx View", new Date()),
            new Course(6, "Spring MVC XlsxStreaming View", new Date())
    );

I am trying to  didvide the List Equally among 3 threads and write to excel
```

The output i am seeing is only 2 records are being shown (4 and 5)

This is my program

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractXlsxView;

import com.memorynotfound.model.Course;

public class XlsxView extends AbstractXlsxView {

    private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
                                      Workbook workbook,
                                      HttpServletRequest request,
                                      HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
         List<Course> collect = (List<Course>) model.get("courses");
        int partitionSize = 112;
        List<List<Course>> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < collect.size();i += partitionSize){
            partitions.add(collect.subList(i,i + Math.min(partitionSize, collect.size() - i)));
        }

          ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        try
        {
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"my-xlsx-file.xlsx\"");
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Spring MVC AbstractXlsxView");
        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
        header.createCell(0).setCellValue("ID");
        header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Name");
        header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Date");
        for (List<Course> list : partitions) {
            exec.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     int rowCount = 1;
                     for (Course course : list){
                         Row courseRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
                         courseRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(course.getId());
                         courseRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(course.getName());
                         courseRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(DATE_FORMAT.format(course.getDate()));
                     }

                }
            });

        }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            if (!exec.isTerminated()) {
                System.err.println("cancel non-finished tasks");
            }
            exec.shutdownNow();
            System.out.println("shutdown finished");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: All threads using the same sheet and all of them are writing it from row 1. So the result is not surprise because last visiting thread overwrites other threads' edits.

Comment: Thanks for the point made , any guess on how to approach this ?

Comment: pass threads a parameter writng start row and give it a try.